# can't run php file , getiing error 403

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Access denied !

Error 403 when trying to launch my php code, I have changed Apache root in http.conf but still get the same error message.

I have saved my files in C:\xampp\php\www
and changed the root in http.conf to c:\xampp\php\www

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making the edits?

Comment: yeah , hopefully problem solved , i copied my website to the C:\xampp\htdocs and changed the http.conf path to  C:\xampp\htdocs and it worked ,